# How to fix special character before £ sign - Â£399 - Spring boot json

Tags: mysql, json, spring-boot, java-8

I create data using Angular-spring boot app. while writing to file from form, I use belwo UTF_8 ecoding
//java 11

FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(Paths.get(activityFile.getRef()).toFile(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);

The file looks ok in notepad - no special characters etc

But I use that file to load to DB and I see problem.

//java 8

```
try (FileReader reader = new FileReader(queFile)){
        
            List<QuackDTO> qDTOs = objectMapper.readValue(reader, new TypeReference<List<QuackDTO>>(){});
}
```

If I see the value in one of the property it is adding Â before £ - like Â£100

As I want an object list  I am not doing a string like

> Files.readString(path, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);

how can I fix my encoding issue?

Where do I see the problem?

file -> list of VOs ->  each VO -> converted to entity type. I already see property having the unwanted character Â

**edit**:

DB is mysql , but I see the special character even before creating entity object

SELECT default_character_set_name FROM information_schema.SCHEMATA WHERE schema_name = "mysch";

> utf8mb4

Comment: What database are you using? Please add its tag to your question. What encoding have you specified for the database and/or column?

Comment: @Bohemian added db. I use CloudSQL for production

Comment: fixed using the code - try (Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(questionsFile), "UTF-8")){

Answer (score 1):

I update code to use - InputStreamReader with UTF-8 encoding

```
try (Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(questionsFile), "UTF-8")){
    List<QuackDTO> qDTOs = objectMapper.readValue(reader, new TypeReference<List<QuackDTO>>(){});
}
```